# ProgressBar always stays at 0 % but the log statement shows me the incremented percentage

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am posting some json data to the server which is working perfectly but i wanted to check the progress of the data sent so i added a progressbar to indicate me the percent of data sent ,but the progressbar stays at 0% , so i put a log statement where i can see the progressbar incrementing by 5 .

This is the code i have tried.

Asynctask class

```
 private class SyncPodData extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Add_Pod.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("POD details syncing.. please wait !!!");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new 
        DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog.cancel();
                new SyncPodData().cancel(true);
            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String IMEI_No = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            if (IMEI_No == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Problem IMEI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    cursor = quickSnapHelper.getPodSyncDetails(oldSYnc);
                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    }
                    else{
                        try{
                            HTTPCalls httpCalls = new HTTPCalls();
                            JSONObject jsonObj = httpCalls.jo(url, 
                            imeiNumber, verificationCode, appName);
                            String token = jsonObj.getString("Token");
                            String tUrl = jsonObj.getString("Url");
                            tUrl = tUrl.toString().concat("postImage");
                            JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray();
                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                                json.put("CategoryName","POD");
                                json.put("SubCategory", passedType);
                                json.put("Image1", image1);
                                json.put("Image2", image2);
                                json.put("Image3", image3);
                                json.put("Image4", image4);
                                json.put("DODC", doe);
                                jArray1.put(json);
                            }
                            int jsonarrayLength = jArray1.length();
                            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                            HttpClient client = new  
                            DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(tUrl);
                            request.setHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);
                            request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, 
                            "application/json");

                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                            Log.d("Http Response:  ", response.toString());
                            statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                            code = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            if (entity != null) {
                                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                               // publish progress //
                                while(count != 100){
                                    publishProgress(count);
                                    count += 5;
                                }

                                BufferedReader reader = new 
                            BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                                String line1;
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null)  
                                {
                                    sb.append(line1);
                                }
                                String result = sb.toString();
                                result = result.trim();
                                instream.close();
                                Log.d("Result:", result);
                                String responseCode = String.valueOf(code);
                                Log.d("Code:", responseCode);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = 
                                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    resultTransId =  
                                    jsonObject.getString("TransactionId");
                                }
                                Log.d("Transaction Id", resultTransId);
                                if (code >= 400) {
                                    Add_Pod.this.runOnUiThread(new  
                                        Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                           "Data sync failed!!!"+"\n"+
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else if (code == 200 && 
                                transId.equals(resultTransId)) {
                                    updaterow();
                                    Add_Pod.this.runOnUiThread(new 
                                      Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                            "Data sync completed",     
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                        catch (UnknownHostException ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Add_Pod.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please    
              check your internet connection!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Add_Pod.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data  
                                            sync failed!!!"+"\n"+
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog(Add_Pod.this, "No Internet Connection",  
                    "You don't have internet connection.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.d("Progress Value", "" + values[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Need some suggestions please.

LogCat :

D/Progress Value﹕ 5
D/Progress Value﹕ 10
D/Progress Value﹕ 15
D/Progress Value﹕ 20
D/Progress Value﹕ 25
D/Progress Value﹕ 30
D/Progress Value﹕ 35
D/Progress Value﹕ 40
D/Progress Value﹕ 45
D/Progress Value﹕ 50
D/Progress Value﹕ 55
D/Progress Value﹕ 60
D/Progress Value﹕ 65
D/Progress Value﹕ 70
D/Progress Value﹕ 75
D/Progress Value﹕ 80
D/Progress Value﹕ 85
D/Progress Value﹕ 90
D/Progress Value﹕ 95

Answer (score 0):

inside your AsyncClass declare two int variable called length and calculatedVal.After declaring HttpEntity variable,inside the if block where entity!=null condition you provided,
initialize length as :

```
 length = entity.getContentLength();
```

inside your onProgressUpdate(), initialize the calculatedVal as well as set the progress value as:

```
 calculatedVal = (int) (((double) values[0] / length) * 100);
 mProgressDialog.setProgress(calculatedVal);
```

you need to show in the progress bar about how much of the file has been downloaded as well as how much is still left.For that you need to consider the top stated calculated value.Hope It will help you

Comment: not working , the progressbar does not even go ahead , it is stuck at 0%
first of all int length gives error , length works with long